# Facing issue "VSTTExecution cannot be found" when running tests through MSTestConsole

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I have .Net Framework 4.8 Project where I have added Asp.Net Core packages for including Extent Reports - But now when I am executing cases through a command from MSBuild.exe and MSTestConsoleRunnerPath(C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe) then tests fails with "Error" and do not have any logged message

But when I checked in Event Viewer - It has logged the below error

```
The description for Event ID 0 from source VSTTExecution cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event: 

(MSTest.exe, PID 29564, Thread 12) OutOfProcessStrategy.StartAgentProcess: The agent was shutdown while starting the agent process.  Cleaning up by killing the agent process, if it exists.

The message resource is present but the message was not found in the message table
```

Package.config

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="AForge" version="2.2.5" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="AForge.Imaging" version="2.2.5" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="AForge.Math" version="2.2.5" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Antlr3.Runtime" version="3.5.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Crc32C.NET" version="1.0.5.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="DnsClient" version="1.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.4.4" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="ExtentReports" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Iesi.Collections" version="4.0.4" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="ImageComparison" version="2.0.4" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="iTextSharp" version="5.5.13" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Magick.NET-Q8-AnyCPU" version="7.9.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Core" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.Abstractions" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.Abstractions" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.Abstractions" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Abstractions" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Abstractions" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common" version="2.8.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp" version="2.8.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CSharp" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Edge.SeleniumTools" version="3.141.2" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventSource" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Options" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="MongoDB.Bson" version="2.10.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="MongoDB.Driver" version="2.10.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="MongoDB.Driver.Core" version="2.10.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="MongoDB.Libmongocrypt" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="NConfig" version="1.1.23" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="12.0.3" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Noksa.WebDriver.ScreenshotsExtensions" version="0.1.5.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="NuGet.CommandLine" version="4.6.2" targetFramework="net461" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="RazorEngine.NetCore" version="2.2.6" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Remotion.Linq" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Remotion.Linq.EagerFetching" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver" version="0.27.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Selenium.InternetExplorer.WebDriver" version="3.12" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Selenium.Support" version="3.141.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Selenium.WebDriver" version="3.141.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver" version="2.40.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Selenium.WebDriver.GeckoDriver" version="0.29.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Selenium.WebDriver.MicrosoftDriver" version="17.17134.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Selenium.WebDriver.MicrosoftWebDriver" version="10.0.16299" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Selenium.WebDriver.MSEdgeDriver" version="88.0.705.56" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Selenium.WebDriver.NetCoreWebDriverFactory" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="SharpCompress" version="0.23.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Snappy.NET" version="1.1.1.8" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Svg" version="2.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.AppContext" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Buffers" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Collections" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Collections.Concurrent" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Collections.Immutable" version="1.5.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Console" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Data.SqlClient" version="4.7.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Debug" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.StackTrace" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Tools" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Dynamic.Runtime" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Globalization" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.IO" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.IO.Compression" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.IO.FileSystem" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.IO.Pipelines" version="4.5.2" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Linq" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Linq.Expressions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Memory" version="4.5.1" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Numerics.Vectors" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Reflection" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Reflection.Emit" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Reflection.Metadata" version="1.6.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Resources.ResourceManager" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Runtime" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" version="4.5.1" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.InteropServices" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Numerics" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Security.AccessControl" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Cng" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Security.Permissions" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Security.Principal.Windows" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Text.Encoding" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Text.Encoding.CodePages" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Text.Encoding.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Text.Encodings.Web" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Threading" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Tasks" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  

    <package id="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" version="4.5.1" targetFramework="net48" />
      <package id="System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
      <package id="System.Threading.Thread" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
      <package id="System.ValueTuple" version="4.5.0-preview1-26216-02" targetFramework="net48" />
      <package id="System.Xml.ReaderWriter" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />

  <package id="System.Xml.XDocument" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Xml.XmlDocument" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Xml.XPath" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Xml.XPath.XDocument" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
</packages>
```

Comment: What is your vs version? And you can try [this link] first (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8b45e925-5330-435a-b6de-53a5945ee704/the-description-for-event-id-0-in-source-vsttexecution-cannot-be-found-the-local-computer?forum=vstswebtest)

Comment: @Tisa - my Visual Studio version is 2019 - And I did  not get anything from the mentioned link:(

Can you please help me here?